# Button action not working on single click instead on double click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Good day. I am using JQUERY Mobile and developing a dynamic selection list view. When I click the `'getGrouping'` button to append, it works on single click. When I click the `'getDel'` button on single click it wont remove until I do it a second time. Has anyone ran into this before? Did I forget to refresh something? It goes through the function on single click every time just removes on the second go around.

How do I execute a single click function that eliminates the last child of a selection without double clicking? Any help is most appreciated.

```
$(document).on('click','#getGrouping',      function(){  // Add list
    var listCreated = false;
     ch = ch + 1;
    $("#listMain").append("<li><li id = 'numLi-" +  ch + "' data-role='collapsible' data-iconpos='right' data-shadow='false' data-corners='false'><h2>Build Tag Group</h2>"
     + " <div class='ui-bar ui-bar-a' style='height: 680px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;'>"
     + " <div class='ui-grid-b'><div class='ui-block-a'></div><div class='ui-block-b'><h1 id='listTitle'></h1></div>"
     + " <div class='ui-block-c'><button id = 'refreshTag'>Refresh</button></div></div></li>");
    listCreated = true;
    $("#listMain").trigger("create");
    $("#listMain ul").listview("refresh");  
    glob = $("#listMain li").children().size() + 1; 
    alert(glob);

});
$(document).on('click','#getDel',      function(){   // delete last row of list
    glob = $("#listMain li").children().size() -1 ; 
    $("#listMain li").last().remove();          
    $("#listMain ul").listview("refresh");  
    $("#getDel").button("refresh");

});
```

Comment: what is that: `.append("<li><li...` ?

Comment: Good catch. That was it! Thank you.